# Passing JavaScript function to another function within object loses object variable scope

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I have a 3rd-party library that performs Facebook authentication and I need to pass it a callback handler. This works fine, but in the callback function it cannot set other params of the object.

I created this simple test and need help to understand why the 3rd case does not work, to simulate what is happening in my app.

```
const Test = {
 uid: null,
 test() {
    this.testAgain(this.updateUID);
 },
 testAgain(updater) {
   updater(7);
 },
 updateUID(id) {
   this.uid = id;
 }
};

alert(Test.uid); // expect null, got null

Test.updateUID(3);
alert(Test.uid); // expect 3, got 3

Test.test();
alert(Test.uid); // expect 7, got 3 ???
```

I appreciate suggestions on how to get the 3rd case to work. I have to pass the function to the Facebook auth library and when FB calls that function, it needs to be able to update params of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass that method in as an argument the reference to the object gets 'stripped' so to speak. So when you are setting this.uid, it's setting a property on an object that is no longer 'Test'. To keep the reference you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
test() {
  this.testAgain(this.updateUID.bind(this));
},
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks. I will accept answer in 5 minutes when it allows me.